# Query for MAX/MIN of non-clustered index field for partitioned table

Tags: sql-server, index, partitioning, nonclustered-index, max

We have a table partitioned on a two-year based hash function from the system date at the insertion time (let's call it `PartitionKey`). It also has a non-clustered index on a single field (`Key`). We insert millions of rows a day.

If I run the below query, will it be resolved solely based on the non-clustered index on `Key`?

```
SELECT MAX(Key), MIN (Key) FROM MyTable
```

Comment: You can request `SHOWPLAN` permissions to be granted without needing to ask for write access. That permission can be granted independently

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Supposing following setup

```
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION [pf](INT) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES (1,2,3,4,5)

CREATE PARTITION SCHEME [ps] AS PARTITION [pf] ALL TO ([PRIMARY])

CREATE TABLE T1(
 [PartitionKey] INT ,
 [Key]          INT IDENTITY NOT NULL ,
 Filler         CHAR(200) NULL,
 INDEX IX([Key]) ON ps([PartitionKey])
)ON ps([PartitionKey]);

INSERT INTO T1([PartitionKey])
SELECT TOP 300000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID) %5
FROM   sys.all_objects o1,
       sys.all_objects o2
```

Then the query

```
SELECT MAX([Key]), MIN ([Key])
FROM T1
```

has execution plan

[image]

The index is used but only as something to scan. Each partition has its own `IX` index so the scan just ends up visiting all the `IX` indexes from all 6 partitions and scanning all of them.

A sometimes better way is to get the max and min from each partition individually (using the order of the index within each partition) - and then get a global aggregated results from these inputs.

The query for that approach could be

```
SELECT MAX(MaxKey) AS MaxKey, MIN(MinKey) AS MinKey
FROM sys.partitions AS p
CROSS APPLY
(
SELECT MAX([Key]) AS MaxKey, MIN ([Key]) AS MinKey
FROM T1
WHERE
$PARTITION.pf(T1.[PartitionKey]) = p.[partition_number]
) AS ca
WHERE
p.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T1', N'U')
AND p.index_id <= 1
```

For each of the 6 partitions this then visits the index in the relevant partition and reads the top and bottom row from its copy of the `IX` index. So reads up to 12 rows rather than 300,000 in this example.

[image]